# Prolog - return whole clause

Tags: prolog, clause

I have some basic formulas like

```
female(camilla).
female(diana).
...
parent(person, child).
...
```

and predicate `language/2` that specifies which predicates will I be using:

```
langugage(female, 1).
language(parent, 2).
```

What I have to do is to create predicate called `body_lit/1` that returns whole clauses specified in language like this:

```
?- body_lit(X).
X = parent(charles, harry) ;
X = parent(diana, harry) ;
...
X = female(camilla) ;
X = female(diana) ;
...
```

I know I need to use `call/n` function and `functor/3`. I know how `functor/3` works but I cant seem to figure out how to return the whole clause instead of just the name of the predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that body_lit is supposed to return all answers to predicates given in language with their arities.

```
body_lit(X) :- language(N,A), functor(F,N,A), call(F), X=F.
```

`language/2` selects a predicate, `functor/3` constructs an actual call from the predicate name and its arity, `call/1` executes the call, and finally `X=F` records the call as the output argument. The last unification could have been removed:

```
body_lit(X) :- language(N,A), functor(X,N,A), call(X).
```